# Is SAP Fiori only/mostly meant for mobile development?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I struggle to understand where to position SAP Fiori against SAP UI5 development.

I know, that the so called Fioris are an expanding list of SAP Web-Apps based on the technology of SAP UI5.

Currently, I am doing Fiori and SAPUi5 practices. When developing Fiori, I have to require

```
data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
```

and it seems I only encounter code snippets using XML as the View language of choice.

When developing SAPUI5, I have to require

```
data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons"
```

and mostly see View coding based on JavaScript.

So, is there a rule of thumb to say that Fiori is for mobile and SAPUI5 for desktop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could say that `sap.ui.commons` was the "old" desktop library, and `sap.m` was the "old" mobile".
Currently, with the Fiori design language, `sap.m` now stands for "main", i.e. it caters for both (responsive) desktop and mobile use. I for one never looked back at `sap.ui.commons`

Comment: Thank you, this answer already helped me a lot. It also explains, why "sap.m" is the default setting in Eclipse for new projects. 

How about the XML- and JavaScript topic? Is XML the prefered way to go?

Comment: The Fiori apps use XML, and my personal preference would be XML too (easier/quicker to write, easier to maintain) but SAP did the right thing and allowed you to use XML/HTML declarative views, as wel as JS/JSON views, whatever your personal preference is. No real mandated recommendation here

Comment: Yes, we can see only 3 UI Controls left in "only for desktop", for sap.ui.commons. All other UI controls are in "Responsive" (general) category, for sap.m package. We can check here: https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design/explore/.